# Intermittent OLE DB error from MSDASQL for OPENQUERY call to MySql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, linked-server, openquery

I have a SQL statement running in SQL Server 2012 that sometimes works fine (returns a little over 4,000 rows in about 25 seconds) and sometimes fails after about 9 1/2 minutes with the error:

> The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "Helpdesk" indicates
>   that either the object has no columns or the current user does not
>   have permissions on that object.

Here is the statement:

```
SELECT  * 
  FROM  OpenQuery(Helpdesk,
            'SELECT ticketpostid,ticketid,dateline,userid,fullname,subject,editeddateline,contents,responsetime,staffid
              FROM  swticketposts
             WHERE  ticketpostid    > 6609667'
        )
```

Helpdesk is a Linked SQL that connects to a remotely located MySQL 5.5 server via an ODBC System DSN.

What are the possible causes of getting this error intermittently?

Comment: "4,000 rows in about 25 seconds" ? : 4K rows should be near instant.  You might have network issues.

Comment: As I said, it is a remote server. To be more specific, it is not on our LAN. I don't know what our bandwidth is for the connection to the remote site, but it is apparently not great. On the other hand, this is a table of over 6 million rows and I don't know what it has in terms of a primary key or indexes.